# Order an Array by Value of Key

Tags: php

Here is my current code to add to the array:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $exp) {
    $activities[] = array('type' => 'level', 'exp' => $exp->exp, 'timestamp' => $badge->timestamp);
}
```

How would I go about sorting this array according to the value of the 'timestamp' key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use `usort` which will let you sort the array using a user-defined function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Example:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

Comment: As a bonus, you can use an anonymous function or lambda as your user-defined function.

Comment: @Sneaksta they are both values of the array. Take a look at the link to the manual, it should explain it to you.

Comment: I didn't end up using your exact answer, but something similar with the uasort function. Thanks!

Comment: @Sneaksta thanks! `uasort` is for sorting and maintaining key relationships, but since your activities variable is just numeric, you probably don't need that.

Comment: Ah okay. Well I'm fairly sure it's working the way I need it to. If not, I may ask for some more help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function array-multisort for the actual sorting, also I would store the values differently:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $exp) {
  $activities[$badge->timestamp] = array('type' => 'level',... );
}
array_multisort($activities, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I'm trying to put strtotime($badge->timestamp) as the key, but it won't accept it. It only seems to like letters for the key, not numbers. Why is this?